# What is the advantage of archiving C object files in a static library (.a file)?

Tags: libraries, c, archive

I mean, as opposed to just linking to individual modules/object files.  Why are groups of modules archived together?  Doesn't it make the executable 1. larger, and 2. less secure (i.e. more vulnerable to return-oriented programming attacks)?

Comment: You seem to believe linking against a static library adds all object files in the library to the final executable. That's not the case, only object files that are actually referenced are added to the executable.

Comment: @SatoKatsura you should turn that into an answer...

Answer (score 5):

The main feature of static libraries is the symbol index that allows you to link in only those archive members that provide missing symbols.

Grouping object files into a single file, or compression, are both secondary, and you can have so-called "thin archives", which do neither. (Thin archives are basically just reference files that exist outside of the object files they refer to).

Answer (score 2):

The advantage: you have just one file.

A static library is just an archive. You can put in and get out individual files as you like. When you link a program, only the appropriate files are extracted and linked.

Note: if you are using a Linux distribution with `dpkg`, you are using the same archiving tool for libraries and packages (and possibly nested in a -dev package).

Comment: Umm... Libraries and packages use different archiving tools!

Comment: @StephenKitt: not really. `dpkg` uses `ar` (so same tools as libraries) and `rpm` uses `cpio`. No need to create a new tool.

Comment: I'll grant you that they use the same external storage formats, but the tools used to build libraries and packages are different (even resorting to low-level tools, you need `ranlib` or `ar -s` for a library; you need `ar` and `tar` and at least one compressor for a `.deb` package). The way you phrased it sort of suggests that a library package can be used as a library. (Also, `-dev` packages aren't supposed to contain libraries — well, only static libraries, if absolutely necessary.)

Comment: Right. I need to write the answer better.